# How to customize a SafeHtml element using GWT?

Tags: xml, gwt

Assume that I have a safehtml element in my xml file, like:

```
<ui:safehtml ui:field="emptyPolicyBlurb"/>
```

When I try to reference it in my Java code using:

```
@UiField SafeHtml emptyPolicyBlurb;
```

My IDE complains that:

```
Expected 'com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml', but 'com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element' found
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Tag names are case sensitive  try this

```
<ui:SafeHtml ui:field="emptyPolicyBlurb"/>
```